Is there a way to Instance An Object on an Index linked to Multiple Edges?
So Lets Say I have a mesh that Looks Like this, and if I were to map Each Index Number this would be the Result.
Is there a Geometry Node setup that Could procedurally find a unique vertex Like this?

Compare Vertex Count of Vertex Neighbors

To instantiate objects at a point where several lines meet, as shown in your example, you can compare the number of neighboring vertices with the value $2$.
The nodes Vertex Neighbors and Compare help you with this.
Something like this:


